# Связь размера ячейки ОЗУ и разрядности шины данных

Tags: память

В сети очень много статей и видео на тему шин:

- «[Устройство ПК :: Системный блок :: Магистраль](http://gdpk.narod.ru/blok/usb.html)»,
- «[Системная шина процессора](http://www.computer-museum.ru/technlgy/proclect/mp/sysbus.htm)»,
- «[Архитектура ПЭВМ. Магистрально-модульный принцип](http://dssp.petrsu.ru/p/tutorial/informatics/chapter3/8/85.htm)»,
- «[Глава 1. Компьютер. Программное и аппаратное обеспечение](http://files.school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore/7e246a27-f9a4-41f1-9edc-01c21ae4d12f/umk/text/01t05.htm)»,
- видео «[Шина компьютера, оперативная память, процессор и мосты](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMx501A3rkY)»,
- «[Устройство оперативной памяти компьютера](http://iguania.ru/article/ram)»,
- «[Центральные и внешние устройства ЭВМ](http://salpk-apk.narod.ru/gl04_2.htm)».

### Вопросы

#### Получившие ответ:

- Каков размер ячейки памяти ОЗУ в современных компьютерах?
- Что означает разрядность процессора *(32 или 64 бита)*?

#### Оставшиеся:

- Сколько бит вернет оперативная память по шине данных, если мы обратимся к конкретной ячейке?
- Как процессор различает данные в 8, 16, 32 бит в 32 битной шине?
- Запрос 32 бит данных из ОЗУ будет происходить в 4 этапа или произойдет за одну итерацию?
- Как просиходит запись в ОЗУ данных, занимающих больше 1 байта?

Comment: Вы случайно не путаете минимальный адресуемый объём памяти и и размер шины данных?

Comment: Вопрос хоть и странный, но ответ есть: 8 бит (1 байт)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505310/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9/505331#505331

Comment: Посмотрите спецификации контроллеров памяти. вот например DDR3-контроллер http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sprugv8e/sprugv8e.pdf  команды чтения и записи оперируют в нем блоками по 8 слов (128 бит). Никто в наше время не будет тратить такты шины на передачу меньшего объема

Answer (score 5):

Если очень кратко, то программно (логически) минимально адресуется 8 бит, т.е. 1 байт (как уже Вам  сказали).

Реально современные процессоры оперирует данными в регистрах разного размера (типично 64-бит) и типа. "Единичный" байт получается путем маскирования "ненужных" бит.

Физически для обмена между кэшем (L3) процессора и памятью, а также для связи кэшей процессоров (ядер)  используют несколько  64-бит каналов, внутренние шины процессора 128 и 256 бит. Т.о. обменов по одному байту не бывает.

В качестве примера можете почитать про [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64),  [Intel QuickPath Interconnect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect) и [Intel Xeon chipsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Xeon_chipsets)

Answer (score 3):

1. Статья «[Машинное слово](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.88.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D0.B0.D1.80.D1.85.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.85)» в Википедии.
2. Годная статья «[О разрядности процессоров](http://www.ixbt.com/cpu/cpu-bitness.shtml)» на IXBT.

Вообще, обычно при указании разрядности процессора пишут количество памяти, которое он *может адресовать*. Количество же бит, которое вернется *при обращении к памяти*, зависит от *разрядности шины данных*.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я знаю, под разрядностью процессора, как было сказано выше, понимают количество памяти которым он может оперировать. 32-битная архитектура использует адресное пространство `0x0-0xffffffff`, в то время как 64-битная `0x0-0xffffffffffffffff`. Адрес ссылается на одну ячейку памяти размером 1 байт.
Возьмём целое 32-битное(4-байтное) число `0x31ABCDEF` (unsigned int в c++, например). Допустим оно лежит по адресу `0x0000ac00`. Тогда памяти оно будет располагаться следующим образом:

```
0x0000ac00: 0x31
0x0000ac01: 0xAB
0x0000ac02: 0xCD
0x0000ac03: 0xEF
```

Comment: а как будет выглядеть команда записи этого числа (размером 32 бита) в память? "Запиши число размером 32 бита по адресу 0x0000ac00" и число автоматически займет ячейки с 0x0000ac00 по 0x0000ac03 или, как я уже писал выше, "запиши первые 8 бит числа (раз уж размер ячейки памяти 8 бит) туда-то, вторые 8 бит туда-то и т.д.", а само число будет отправлено по шине данных целиком?

Comment: @jumpjet67 Что то мне подсказывает, что вне зависимости от используемой команды (есть команды для оперирования как отдельными байтами, так и 16/32/64, а для sse команд доступны размеры плоть до 512 бит на современных процессорах intel) данные попадут в кеш процессора. А кеш независимо от выполняемой ранее команды, когда сочтет нужным, сбросит эти данные в память и при этом он будет оперировать размером шины.